# How to set AUTO disconnection in JAVA within Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, datasource

I'm having a problem that my application runs out available connections on connection pool often recently. Even that we found out it's 3rd party vendor's JAR that didn't close the Datasource connection they created properly, we still need to find a way to CLOSE created connection after certain time.

I tried to edit Connection Reserve Timeout in Advance block under Connection Pool tag, but it doesn't working and I didn't see other field seem like the thing I want. So I need to find a way to achieve it using JAVA code, and a way to verify that it works.

Can anyone tell me how to set DB auto disconnect time interval on JAVA? With a way to verify it would be appreciated. =D

Comment: Should it be _Inactive Connection Timeout_ instead?

Comment: @Alex kinda like it. but no confirmation until I checked that it does what I want. any good reference about it?

Comment: Oracle official web page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jdbcconnectionpool_config_connections.html

Comment: Weird, I can't find that field? can you tell me where I can it in Weblogic's web console?

Comment: I can't help you then. I don't have WebLogic server setup. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/JDBCA/ds_tuning.htm this link is more recent.

Comment: Hmm, I could still use the JAVA code if I cannot do and verify the `Inactive Connection Timeout` on weblogic